# Chrome CA cert Security Error

Tags: macos, google-chrome, certificate

A few days ago Chrome stopped accepting my CA certificates. Now it just says:

> Invalid Server Certificate   You
>   attempted to reach *my-domain*, but the
>   server presented an invalid
>   certificate.

Here's a screengrab:

[image: Invalid Server Certificate]

I'm running Chrome 11.0.696.57 on OS X. I've also tried this with Chrome 10.0.648 on Ubuntu. Under Safari and Firefox I'm able to access the site without problems.

BTW, I have already installed the certificate file in my Keychain (under System keychains.)

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong? How do I let Chrome enter this site?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Chrome -> Preferences -> Under the Hood -> HTTPS/SSL

Uncheck 'Check for server certificate revocation'